# Show that $V = \{ f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \ | \ \text{if} \ x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\} \ \text{then} \ f(x)=0\}$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in \Bbb R$ and,
>
> $$V = \{ f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \ | \ \text{if} \ x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\} \ \text{then} \ f(x)=0\}$$
> Show that $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$

We follow the subspace criterion

**1)** $0(x) = 0$ so $V$ is non-empty.

**2)** Let $f,g \in V$ and $k_1, k_2 \in \Bbb R$. Then we have to show that $k_1 f + k_2 g \in V$. I see that the proof would end as follows $(k_1 f + k_2 g)(x) = k_1 \underbrace{f(x)}_{=0} + k_2 \underbrace{g(x)}_{=0} = 0$.

However, I am missing prior steps... Might you please help me out to see how to complete **2)**?

Comment: Assume that $x \notin \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \},$ where $f, g \in V$.  What, then, do we know about $f(x)$?  What do we know about $g(x)$?  What conclusion can we draw about $k_1f(x)+k_2g(x)$?

Comment: Just add that this equality holds for $x\in \mathbb R\backslash\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2), we would just say:

Suppose $f, g \in V$. I claim that $k_1 f + k_2 g \in V$. For consider some $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{a_1, ..., a_1\}$. Then $(k_1 f + k_2 g)(x) = k_1 f(x) + k_2 g(x) = 0$. So $k_1 f + k_2 g \in V$.

Note that we can actually prove this quite elegantly. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, and consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{a_1, ..., a_n\}}$. Then there is an obvious linear map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{a_1, ..., a_n\}}$ which is the restriction homomorphism: that is, $\phi(f) = f|_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{a_1, ..., a_n\}}$, or, in more detail, $\phi(f)(x) = f(x)$.

Then $V = \ker(\phi)$. So $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.